# Error when using ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo

Tags: android

I am running android 2.1 and wants to get currently running apps, after running following code I am getting error: The application has stopped unexpectedly

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(100);   //error
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [GET_TASKS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS) permission to your manifest.